# Understanding CSS rendering

Tags: css, browser

So I read everywhere that CSS is *render blocking*. Though this is different than the blocking caused by `<script>` tag as it does not pause parsing of HTML. The browser basically waits for the *CSSOM* to be constructed and then only render anything to the webpage. Therefore, when CSS is loaded late, it can effect load time for your webpage. But what I don't understand is that if this is the case, how is FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) caused? FOUC is basically when the browser momentarily displays HTML without the styling, and then when the CSS is available, it displays the correctly styled page. So if browser always waits for the CSS to be loaded and parsed first before rendering anything, FOUC should not happen.

Comment: The CSSOM can be built before async requests end, and probably even before sync operations are all performed (for instance in FireFox, [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4b8d7kc/) will render the unstyled document until you close the alert, Chrome behaves differently here)

Answer (score 0):

> if browser always waits for the CSS to be loaded and parsed first before rendering anything, FOUC should not happen.

Indeed, that's what should happen in such a case, except that browsers don't wait for all resources to be loaded before rendering.

Note that this doesn't contradict what you "read everywhere", if you really did read "*The browser basically waits for the CSSOM to be constructed and then only render anything to the webpage.*"

The browser can very well build the CSSOM while it still misses resources, for instance, it definitely doesn't need to load all background-images resources to calculate the elements' box positions.
And it may actually even *need* to build the CSSOM as soon as the DOM is being constructed because in cases like the below snippet, you need the CSSOM for the js to work:

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<script>
  // without CSSOM, we couldn't get its width yet
  console.log(document.querySelector('h1').offsetWidth);
</script>
<style>
  /* even if it's gonna be invalidated later on */
  h1 { width: 300px; border:1px solid; } 
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't really address my question. "The browser can very well build the CSSOM while it still misses resources" - these resources doesn't include HTML I believe. Missing images doesn't cause FOUC, but HTML nodes not having associated CSS do.

Comment: @maverick FOUC happens with *external* stylesheets, which are *external* resources and which loading won't block the parsing of the document. And yes the cssom can very well be built before all the html got parsed, like in my example, the <style> node has not been parsed yet when the script is executed.